# Can Not Connect Debian 8 VNC Server Google Cloud Compute

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I've used the following guide in order to connect to a Debian 8 Server with GUI using a DigitalOcean server:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vnc-server-on-debian-8

I know this works, however under Azure and now Google's Cloud Compute I am unable to connect. I think there should be some setting on Google's side that is blocking outside connections through VNC to the Debian 8 instance.

I only have the free support level, and I don't want to upgrade just to resolve this issue alone. Here is a screenshot from my console that perhaps has some relevant information:
[Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgODk.jpg)

I'd appreciate any input anybody could give me. I've tried trouble shooting this before under Azure, but after getting it to work on DigitalOcean, I know the problem isn't from my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution was simple. I just had to allow the port tcp:5901 through Google's firewall in order to connect to my VNC server.